# Mvc when to bind model and when parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When would you use model binding and when parameters?

I have had discussion wit college about using parameters and when to use model

My answer for search filters

Scenario
Public actionresult search(int? UserId, string name, int idtype2, string typeRequest1, string type2){ code}

If I get multiple parameters coming into the action it's better to use model binder, if I have multiple parameters as its easier to work with and model contains all parameters and can be easier extended, especially If I have multiple tests on actionresults as adding new parameter does not involve rewriting all tests with methods

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using normal screen size on get/post actions we are going to use following

1. parameters that fit into one line without scrolling can be as parameters

   1-1.   if anyone is adding new items they might need to convert to model
2. model is used if there is more parameters

   2-1.   When binding model define items to bind form the model. You should bind only what you need.
   using: [Bind(Include = "FieldName")] or [Bind(Exclude = "FieldName")]Model userModel

Answer (score 1):

It's totally a design preference, so heres my ***opinion***

Use a model when it's logical too, so if there are > 2 parameters or if there is extra logic the model needs to do (Such as cleaning the parameters). Or, if you need to re-use the parameters elsewhere.